# Give examples to show that the following definitions of $\lim_{X \to a}=l$ are not correct

Tags: limits

Give examples to show that the following definitions of $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$are not correct

a)For all $\delta$>0 there is an $\epsilon$>0 such that if 0<|x-a|< $\delta$, then |f(x)- $l$|< $\epsilon$

Comment: Is that a 1 or an $l$?  What is $l$ supposed to be?

Comment: Sorry. It should be $l$

Comment: Then just come up with a limt that *isn't* 1.

Comment: Yes. That should be the basic thought. But I just can't give an exact example

Comment: @fleabood it's $l$, not 1.

Comment: @FlyingBirds consider $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, and $a=1$. Do you see what delta values would not work?

Comment: Is it $ \delta $ =1?

Comment: @FlyingBirds Why does $\delta = 1$ not work?

Comment: If epsilon is based on delta rather than the other way around, you can make epsilon way too big to pin point the limits.

Answer (score 2):

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} x$ = 42, 57, and -10.

Pf: For $\delta > 0$ let $\epsilon$ = 500 + $\delta$

Then $|x - 0| < \delta$

$-\delta < x < \delta$

so

$-\delta < f(x) < \delta$

$-\delta-500 < f(x) -42, - 57, + 10 < \delta + 500$

so

$|f(x) - 42, -57, - (-10)| < \epsilon$

See why that doesn't work?
so $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} x$ = 42, 57, and -10.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be defined by
$f(x)=\begin{cases}
1 &\text{if }x\in \mathbb{Q} \\
0 &\text{if }x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}$

and $\epsilon =2$

Here for all $\delta>0$ and $0<|x-a|<\delta$ one has $|f(x)-1|<\epsilon=2$

Comment: So what's the limit? And a limit to what?

Comment: Clearly $a$ can be arbitrary and the pretended role of a limit $l$ can be performed only by $1$ and $0$.